# Max possible number of sets that have 1 and only 1 member in common

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of 25 things that I want to group into sets of 6, with the following conditions:

1. Every set shares one, and only one, member in common with every other set
2. No object can appear twice in a given set (I know this is the mathematical definition of a set, but it bears emphasizing)

How many such combinations exist?

I feel like this is a problem that should be solvable with some form of combinatorics, but the stuff I learned back in college doesn't cover it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is a description of a $6$-regular multigraph on $25$ vertices. Try looking up multigraphs to start with.

Comment: I can't fulfill this at all with 25 items. 21 items is the number I get to.